# Can each user use a different gui on the same machine?

Tags: gui, users, interface

Is it possible for every user using ubuntu 14.04 (or later) to have a different gui interface? I would like to set up ubuntu to replace windows and for my wife would like to install the W7 interface for her but use the unity interface for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. When you log on there is an option to choose the desktop interface you'd like to use. I'm not sure what W7 interface you're talking about, but I'm guessing it's a KDE session with tweaks to make it look like W7. To choose a different desktop interface, first install it.

When you go to log on you should see a button near the user name of the log on screen. the screen below shows what it looked like in previous versions of Ubuntu. I don't use the unity interface any more, so I can't be certain, but I expect it will be near the same spot. Notice that to the right of 'NoobsLab' (the username) there is a small circle with the Gnome icon. Clicking that will bring up a list of options to choose from, based on what desktop environments you have installed.

[image]